# How to save data passed from another activity in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, android-activity

I have used `intent` to pass the `student name` from the initial `StudentNameInput` activity to `StudentInitialActivity` activity. The second activity displays whatever name the user had input in the previous activity. My code is properly displaying the name once the user logs in. However, when I close the app, the name is displayed as `null`. My question is how do I keep displaying the name even after closing and restarting the app. I have already implemented `shared preferences` in my code to keep track of initial startup and hence, the app does not prompt for a name every time the app is opened.

`StudentNameInput` Activity:

```
class StudentNameInput : AppCompatActivity(), View.OnClickListener {

    private lateinit var sharedPref: SharedPreferences

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("YOUR_PREF_NAME", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

        if (wasUserNameSaved()) {
            val intent = Intent(this, StudentInitialActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
            finish()
            return
        }
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_student_name_input)

        btnStudentLogIn.setOnClickListener(this)
    }

    private fun validate(): Boolean {
        if (txt_student_name.text.toString().isEmpty()) {
            txt_student_name.error = "Name cannot be empty"
            return false
        }

        return true
    }

    override fun onClick(v: View?) {
        val editTextStudentName = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.txt_student_name);
        when (v?.id) {
            R.id.btnStudentLogIn -> {
                if (validate()) {
                    Log.i(null, "setOnClickListener")
                    sharedPref.edit().putString("user_name", txt_student_name.text.toString())
                        .apply()

                    val studentName = editTextStudentName.text.toString();
                    val intent = Intent(this@StudentNameInput, StudentInitialActivity::class.java)
                    intent.putExtra("Name", studentName);
                    startActivity(intent)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun wasUserNameSaved(): Boolean {
        return sharedPref.getString("user_name", "").isNotEmpty()
    }
}
```

`StudentInitialActivity` Activity:

```
 class StudentInitialActivity : Activity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_student_initial)

        val intent = intent
        val name = intent.getStringExtra("Name")


        val studentNameTextView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textViewStudentName)

        textViewStudentName.text = "Logged in as: " + name

        btnScanForClasses.setOnClickListener {
            Log.i(null, "setOnClickListener")
            val intent = Intent(this, DeviceScanActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
        btnRecords.setOnClickListener {
            startActivity(Intent(this, StudentRecords::class.java))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use sharepreference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you already storing the user name in StudentNameInput activity and you have written a condition there to check if the name already stored directly take to StudentInitialActivity. So you are missing to get the stored name, I will suggest you this solution-

In StudentNameInput add the name of the user to intent in this block

```
if (wasUserNameSaved()){
   val intent = Intent(this, StudentInitialActivity::class.java)
                    intent.putExtra("Name", sharedPref.getString("YOUR_PREF_NAME", ""))
                    startActivity(intent)
                    finish()
                    return
                }
```

Comment: Earlier if was expecting the name via intent bundle and you were not passing it.